# Joomla Session Variable as Plugin Parameter

Tags: joomla

I have a Joomla plugin which takes varying parameters.  I need to retrieve one of these parameters from the current session.  I've tried using Jumi and a little PHP snipped to retrieve the value and output it in the plugin's parameter list, but the Joomla plugin parser only handles the outter-most set of curly braces.  ex.

```
{fabrik view=table id=62 resetfilters=1 fab_tours_ro___tour_id=[tour_id]}
```

`[tour_id]` I need to retrieve from the current session.  I've tried

```
{fabrik view=table id=62 resetfilters=1 fab_tours_ro___tour_id={jumi [scripts/get_tour_id.php]}}
```

In that case the `{jumi}` tag never gets parsed.  I could hack the `{fabrik}` plugin, but I'd prefer to do this without making any core or component changes, especially since I update Fabrik quite regularly via svn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually ended up using the latest [Jumi 2.1 beta plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jumi/downloads/list) which runs as System rather than Content.  Then it was as simple as echoing the plugin syntax with the value already filled in:

```
{jumi}
<?php
$tour_id = $mainframe->getUserState("tour_id", '0');
echo '{fabrik view=table id=62 resetfilters=1 fab_tours_ro___tour_id='.$tour_id.'}';
?>
{/jumi}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your jumi plugin is executing before your fabrik plugin.  You can check the order they are being fired in Extensions -> Plugin Manager.